# raster2pgsql no more INSERT/COPY statement in the log

Tags: raster, postgis, batch, windows, raster2pgsql

I use `raster2pgsql` every day with Windows command tools, and I'm searching a command to not prompt the `INSERT` or `COPY` statement on the terminal because I've got a lot, like an inverse verbose.

Is it possible or did I will be haunted by this `INSERT` forever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux ([more info](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/163352)):

```
raster2plpgsql [<options>] <raster> >> /dev/null
```

On Windows ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/313115)):

```
raster2plpgsql.exe [<options>] <raster> > NUL
```